# The choice of the day is not through the select, but through the calendar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On my page there is a form for filling out and reserving free places in a restaurant. In this form, you can select the day and time. The time is pulled together for each restaurant separately in the database using jsona and hides the excess, leaving only the opening hours of the selected restaurant.

There is also a choice of the day, which is now implemented through a separate select. But I added a bootstrap calendar and I want to choose a date there so that the day is immediately selected.

I need the day to be selected not only through the select that is, but also through the calendar, that is, we click on the date in the calendar, and based on this date, the day in the select is determined.

How can i do this?

The calendar button is the first in the snippet.

```js
let restaurantReserve = {
  init: function() {
    let _self = this;

    $('#reservation-date').datepicker({
      startDate: '+0d'
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
      const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');
      let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]"]');
      input.val(arDate[3] + '-' + (e.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + arDate[2]);
      _self.unSetError(input);
      $('#reservation-date .js-value').text(arDate[2] + ' ' + arDate[1]);
    });

    $('[aria-labelledby="reservation-time"] li a').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[time]"]');
      input.val($(this).data('value'));
      _self.unSetError(input);
      $('#reservation-time .js-value').text($(this).text());
    });
  },
  setError: function(ob) {
    $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).addClass('btn-error');
  },
  unSetError: function(ob) {
    $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).removeClass('btn-error');
  }
}
restaurantReserve.init();
let json = [{
  "id": 86,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Mon",
  "open": "9.30",
  "close": "14.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 87,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Tue",
  "open": "3.00",
  "close": "21.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 88,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Wed",
  "open": "4.30",
  "close": "6.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 89,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Thu",
  "open": "2.30",
  "close": "7.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 90,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Fri",
  "open": "3.00",
  "close": "22.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, /*{"id":91,"restaurant_id":1,"day":"Sat","open":"1.30","close":"4.30","created_at":"2022-02-22 10:56:15"},*/ {
  "id": 91,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Sat",
  "open": "0",
  "close": "4.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 92,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Sun",
  "open": "3.00",
  "close": "20.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 107,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Mon",
  "open": "1.30",
  "close": "19.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 108,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Tue",
  "open": "5.30",
  "close": "8.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 109,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Wed",
  "open": "3.00",
  "close": "20.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 110,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Thu",
  "open": "1.00",
  "close": "12.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 111,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Fri",
  "open": "2.30",
  "close": "12.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 112,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Sat",
  "open": "4.00",
  "close": "22.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 113,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Sun",
  "open": "4.00",
  "close": "22.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}];

function getWorkHours(json, restaurant_id) {
  return json.filter(item => item.restaurant_id == restaurant_id);
}

function getWorkHoursForDay(json, restaurant_id, day) {
  return getWorkHours(json, restaurant_id).filter(item => item.day === day)[0];
}

function filterTimes() {
  let restaurantID = document.getElementById("restaurantid").value;
  let dayofweek = document.getElementById("dayofweek").value;
  if ((["1", "3"].indexOf(restaurantID) >= 0) && ((["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"].indexOf(dayofweek)) >= 0)) {
    let workHours = getWorkHoursForDay(json, restaurantID, dayofweek);
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-height-fixed li a");
    for (let item of items) {
      let itemValueParts = item.innerText.split(" ");
      itemValue = parseFloat(itemValueParts[0]) + (((itemValueParts[1] === "PM") && (itemValueParts[0] !== "00.00")) ? 12 : 0);
      item.parentNode.classList[((itemValue < parseFloat(workHours.open)) || (itemValue > parseFloat(workHours.close)) ? "add" : "remove")]("invisible");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-fourth {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #e3e5e8;
  color: #747b8b;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

ul.with-out>li:before,
.dropdown-menu li:before,
ul.whithout>li:before {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-height-fixed {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-item.active,
.dropdown-item:active {
  background: red;
}

.block-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(32, 35, 44, 0.05);
}

.block-white {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<form id="reservation" action="/restaurants/123/" method="post">
  <div class="block-shadow block-white mb-4">
    <h5 class="fw-bold mb-3">Reserve a table</h5>
    <div class="btn-s">
      <a class="btn btn-fourth " id="reservation-date" data-date=">">
        <span class="icon br-calender"></span> <span class="js-value">-----</span>
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-fourth " id="reservation-time" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon br-clock"></span> <span class="js-value">
                        -- : --                </span>
      </a>
      <select id="restaurantid" onchange="filterTimes()">
        <option>Please Select Restaurant</option>
        <option value="1">Pizza Mia</option>
        <option value="3">Burger Land</option>
      </select>
      <select id="dayofweek" onchange="filterTimes()">
        <option>Please Select Day</option>
        <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
        <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
        <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
        <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
        <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
        <option value="Sat">Sat</option>
        <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
      </select>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-height-fixed" aria-labelledby="reservation-time">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="0.00">00.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="0.30">00.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="1.00">01.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="1.30">01.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="2.00">02.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="2.30">02.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="3.00">03.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="3.30">03.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="4.00">04.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="4.30">04.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="5.00">05.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="5.30">05.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="6.00">06.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="6.30">06.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="7.00">07.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="7.30">07.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="8.00">08.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="8.30">08.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="9.00">09.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="9.30">09.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="10.00">10.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="10.30">10.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="11.00">11.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="11.30">11.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="12.00">00.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="12.30">00.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="13.00">01.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="13.30">01.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="14.00">02.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="14.30">02.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="15.00">03.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="15.30">03.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="16.00">04.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="16.30">04.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="17.00">05.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="17.30">05.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="18.00">06.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="18.30">06.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="19.00">07.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="19.30">07.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="20.00">08.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="20.30">08.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="21.00">09.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="21.30">09.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="22.00">10.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="22.30">10.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="23.00">11.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="23.30">11.30 PM</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field-restaurantreservationform-personcount">
      <input type="hidden" id="restaurantreservationform-personcount" class="form-control" name="RestaurantReservationForm[personCount]" data-btn-id="reservation-person">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field-restaurantreservationform-date required">
      <input type="hidden" id="restaurantreservationform-date" class="form-control" name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]" data-btn-id="reservation-date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field-restaurantreservationform-time">
      <input type="hidden" id="restaurantreservationform-time" class="form-control" name="RestaurantReservationForm[time]" data-btn-id="reservation-time">
    </div>
```

Comment: You got responses and hints already when you asked about this the last time, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71615403/1427878 (which wasn't the first time you asked about this either, IIRC) - why do you keep deleting your question, only to then ask it in the same format again? You are basically signaling to people that they don't need to bother to comment, because you will only throw it all away again anyway.

Comment: Please read [mcve].  It seems about 90% of your html and code are not relevant to the question (eg selecting a time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I clearly understand you, then you need just add `$('#dayofweek').val(arDate[0]);` after this line `const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');`. Here is an example:

```js
let restaurantReserve = {
  init: function() {
    let _self = this;

    $('#reservation-date').datepicker({
      startDate: '+0d'
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
      const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');
      $('#dayofweek').val(arDate[0]);
      filterTimes();
      let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]"]');
      input.val(arDate[3] + '-' + (e.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + arDate[2]);
      _self.unSetError(input);
      $('#reservation-date .js-value').text(arDate[2] + ' ' + arDate[1]);
    });

    $('[aria-labelledby="reservation-time"] li a').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[time]"]');
      input.val($(this).data('value'));
      _self.unSetError(input);
      $('#reservation-time .js-value').text($(this).text());
    });
  },
  setError: function(ob) {
    $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).addClass('btn-error');
  },
  unSetError: function(ob) {
    $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).removeClass('btn-error');
  }
}
restaurantReserve.init();
let json = [{
  "id": 86,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Mon",
  "open": "9.30",
  "close": "14.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 87,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Tue",
  "open": "3.00",
  "close": "21.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 88,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Wed",
  "open": "4.30",
  "close": "6.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 89,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Thu",
  "open": "2.30",
  "close": "7.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 90,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Fri",
  "open": "3.00",
  "close": "22.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, /*{"id":91,"restaurant_id":1,"day":"Sat","open":"1.30","close":"4.30","created_at":"2022-02-22 10:56:15"},*/ {
  "id": 91,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Sat",
  "open": "0",
  "close": "4.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 92,
  "restaurant_id": 1,
  "day": "Sun",
  "open": "3.00",
  "close": "20.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:56:15"
}, {
  "id": 107,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Mon",
  "open": "1.30",
  "close": "19.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 108,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Tue",
  "open": "5.30",
  "close": "8.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 109,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Wed",
  "open": "3.00",
  "close": "20.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 110,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Thu",
  "open": "1.00",
  "close": "12.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 111,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Fri",
  "open": "2.30",
  "close": "12.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 112,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Sat",
  "open": "4.00",
  "close": "22.00",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}, {
  "id": 113,
  "restaurant_id": 3,
  "day": "Sun",
  "open": "4.00",
  "close": "22.30",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22 10:58:59"
}];

function getWorkHours(json, restaurant_id) {
  return json.filter(item => item.restaurant_id == restaurant_id);
}

function getWorkHoursForDay(json, restaurant_id, day) {
  return getWorkHours(json, restaurant_id).filter(item => item.day === day)[0];
}

function filterTimes() {
  let restaurantID = document.getElementById("restaurantid").value;
  let dayofweek = document.getElementById("dayofweek").value;
  if ((["1", "3"].indexOf(restaurantID) >= 0) && ((["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"].indexOf(dayofweek)) >= 0)) {
    let workHours = getWorkHoursForDay(json, restaurantID, dayofweek);
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-height-fixed li a");
    for (let item of items) {
      let itemValueParts = item.innerText.split(" ");
      itemValue = parseFloat(itemValueParts[0]) + (((itemValueParts[1] === "PM") && (itemValueParts[0] !== "00.00")) ? 12 : 0);
      item.parentNode.classList[((itemValue < parseFloat(workHours.open)) || (itemValue > parseFloat(workHours.close)) ? "add" : "remove")]("invisible");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-fourth {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #e3e5e8;
  color: #747b8b;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

ul.with-out>li:before,
.dropdown-menu li:before,
ul.whithout>li:before {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-height-fixed {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-item.active,
.dropdown-item:active {
  background: red;
}

.block-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(32, 35, 44, 0.05);
}

.block-white {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<form id="reservation" action="/restaurants/123/" method="post">
  <div class="block-shadow block-white mb-4">
    <h5 class="fw-bold mb-3">Reserve a table</h5>
    <div class="btn-s">
      <a class="btn btn-fourth " id="reservation-date" data-date=">">
        <span class="icon br-calender"></span> <span class="js-value">-----</span>
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-fourth " id="reservation-time" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon br-clock"></span> <span class="js-value">
                        -- : --                </span>
      </a>
      <select id="restaurantid" onchange="filterTimes()">
        <option>Please Select Restaurant</option>
        <option value="1">Pizza Mia</option>
        <option value="3">Burger Land</option>
      </select>
      <select id="dayofweek" onchange="filterTimes()">
        <option>Please Select Day</option>
        <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
        <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
        <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
        <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
        <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
        <option value="Sat">Sat</option>
        <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
      </select>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-height-fixed" aria-labelledby="reservation-time">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="0.00">00.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="0.30">00.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="1.00">01.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="1.30">01.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="2.00">02.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="2.30">02.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="3.00">03.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="3.30">03.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="4.00">04.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="4.30">04.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="5.00">05.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="5.30">05.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="6.00">06.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="6.30">06.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="7.00">07.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="7.30">07.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="8.00">08.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="8.30">08.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="9.00">09.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="9.30">09.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="10.00">10.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="10.30">10.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="11.00">11.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="11.30">11.30 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="12.00">00.00 AM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="12.30">00.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="13.00">01.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="13.30">01.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="14.00">02.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="14.30">02.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="15.00">03.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="15.30">03.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="16.00">04.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="16.30">04.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="17.00">05.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="17.30">05.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="18.00">06.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="18.30">06.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="19.00">07.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="19.30">07.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="20.00">08.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="20.30">08.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="21.00">09.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="21.30">09.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="22.00">10.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="22.30">10.30 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="23.00">11.00 PM</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="23.30">11.30 PM</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field-restaurantreservationform-personcount">
      <input type="hidden" id="restaurantreservationform-personcount" class="form-control" name="RestaurantReservationForm[personCount]" data-btn-id="reservation-person">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field-restaurantreservationform-date required">
      <input type="hidden" id="restaurantreservationform-date" class="form-control" name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]" data-btn-id="reservation-date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field-restaurantreservationform-time">
      <input type="hidden" id="restaurantreservationform-time" class="form-control" name="RestaurantReservationForm[time]" data-btn-id="reservation-time">
    </div>
```

Comment: yes, that's right, but please note that there is also a choice of a restaurant and there can be a separate time for each day of work, now when you select a date on the calendar it does not change, but when you select a day it changes

Comment: @stopwar Now it changes :) Just add `filterTimes();` after `$('#dayofweek').val(arDate[0]);`